# Is Neo4j newsfeed flawed?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using this example, http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-newsfeed.html, to maintain newsfeeds for my users. So I use the following to post a status update:

```
MATCH (me)
WHERE me.name='Bob'
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[r:STATUS]-(secondlatestupdate)
DELETE r
CREATE (me)-[:STATUS]->(latest_update { text:'Status',date:123 })
WITH latest_update, collect(secondlatestupdate) AS seconds
FOREACH (x IN seconds | CREATE (latest_update)-[:NEXT]->(x))
RETURN latest_update.text AS new_status
```

I encountered a severe flaw in this and don't know how to fix it. In a very rare scenario where two status updates are posted at the exactly same time (ex. 10ms apart), instead of replacing the current status, Neo4j creates two status updates. This leads to a much bigger problem where, the next updates are posted twice!

Comment: Hello @pewpewlasers, are you wrapping the queries in a transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a race condition. To resolve that you basically need to make sure that at a given time only one transaction is modifying the status for this specific user.

Neo4j's Java API does have the ability to set locks to achieve this. Cypher doesn't have an explicit feature for this but you can e.g. remove a non-existing property to force a lock on the given node. With a lock in place concurrent transaction need to wait this the holder of the lock is finished with his transaction.

So grab a lock early in your statement:

```
MATCH (me)
WHERE me.name='Bob'
REMOVE me._not_existing // side effect: grab a lock early
WITH me
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[r:STATUS]-(secondlatestupdate)
DELETE r
CREATE (me)-[:STATUS]->(latest_update { text:'Status',date:123 })
WITH latest_update, collect(secondlatestupdate) AS seconds
FOREACH (x IN seconds | CREATE (latest_update)-[:NEXT]->(x))
RETURN latest_update.text AS new_status
```